# Heroku app giving "status=404" and not showing up

Tags: reactjs, flask, heroku, build, http-status-code-404

I got my app successfully (or at least it seemed to be) uploaded to heroku. Everything said it was successful, but then when I try to hit the "Open App" button on that app's heroku page it returns with a 404 error.

```
2021-03-14T22:35:00.849056+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-14 22:35:00 +0000] [5] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-14T22:35:00.852727+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-14 22:35:00 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-03-14T22:35:00.942754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-14T22:42:41.838136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cupboardcobble.herokuapp.com request_id=605b3d3a-55ac-458a-aa9b-d5e76a1a5331 fwd="73.80.9.120" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=432 protocol=https
```

That is what it shows when I run "heroku logs --tail --app cupboardcobble" in the terminal. If I look up earlier in the log I see the "h10" code, but I have not been able to locate the possible reason for this. This is a react-redux based front end, and a flask based backend with docker. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you set NODE_ENV value to production?

Comment: I don't believe I have a NODE_ENV in this app, in mine I am using FLASK_ENV, and yes it is set to development currently. I should say though, that I cloned this from another app I made and that one works perfectly with all the same environment variables. No idea what is happening.